# Just 30+ markers in Google Maps for Android causes lag when panning

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm having issues with lag when using Google Maps on Android. There is noticeable lag when panning starting at around 30 markers. At 100 markers it's basically unusable. When searching for similar problems, most people seem to start having issues at 1000's of markers (not 100...).

Here's the situation:

1. I'm testing on a Google Pixel, Android 25
2. My project is using `play-services-maps:11.0.1`, min sdk 14, target sdk 25
3. I've setup a simple maps activity (copied from the [Maps for Android - Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start) tutorial).
4. Once the map is ready, I add a bunch of markers like this (no custom icons, just the default marker):`mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pos).title("Marker"));`

Here's a video showing what it looks like at 10, 30, and 100 markers. The lag is much more noticeable on the device (compared to the video).

https://youtu.be/TAjkuSOWar4

Is it normal that panning should start feeling laggy at 30 markers? Or what's going on...?

Comment: Do you have any informations about that? I have motorola z2 play (Android N) and I got exactly the same issue

Comment: also when I click on marker it goes smoothier, so that's weird problem